# Strange behaviour of curl

Tags: php, curl

I was making use of *CURL* and came across a strange behavior of it.

```
$url = 'https://makesif.com/sms/bulksms_m.php';    
foreach($msg as $v) {
$smsparam=array('number' => '+974'.$v[1],'message' => $v[2]);
$url = $url . "?" . http_build_query($smsparam, '&');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
                    }
```

In this usage, the curl was sent with the same value for variable `'number'` with each time curl request. But when I put the URL var definition inside the each command, it worked right. How can this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are making concatenation a new query params with previous URL on each iteration:

```
...
$url = $url . "?" . http_build_query($smsparam, '&'); // <---- 
...
```

So that on some iteration your `$url` may look like:

```
"https://makesif.com/sms/bulksms_m.php?number=%2B974&message=0?number=%2B974&message=1?number=%2B974&message=2?number=%2B974&message=3?number=%2B974&message=4?number=%2B974&message=5"
```

---

The right way would be to add new query params to the initial `$url` like shown below:

```
$url = 'https://makesif.com/sms/bulksms_m.php';    
foreach ($msg as $v) {
    $smsparam = array('number' => '+974'.$v[1],'message' => $v[2]);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . "?" . http_build_query($smsparam));
    ....
```